# Redirect 301 pages from old joomla to new site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have problem with redirecting pages from old site which is Joomla to new site which isn't joomla. I have tried this

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^/page http://newsite.com/pgs/page [R=301,L]
 ^ this redirect to newsite.com/page instead of newsite.com/pgs/page

RewriteRule ^/anotherpage http://www.newsite.com/cat/sub/sub-sub/productindex.php [R=301,L]
 ^ this redirect to newsite.com/anotherpage
```

As you can see it's redirecting only to root/page ... doesn't get sub pages etc. Can anyone help with this?

How to make it if I have 2 or 3 different old url's leading to same new url? like this one:

```
RewriteRule ^/?oldpage http://www.newsite\.com/pgs/services/index.php [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?oldpage2 http://www.newsite\.com/pgs/services/index.php [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?oldpage3 http://www.newsite\.com/pgs/services/index.php [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way by reordering your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^/?anotherpage http://www.newsite.com/cat/sub/sub-sub/productindex.php [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?page http://newsite.com/pgs/page [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear browser cache before testing these rules.